# google maps geocoding changes

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Has anyone noticed that google maps geocoding have changed the variable name of the lat and lng from, Qa and Ra to Pa and Qa.

Does anyone know a reason for this?

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**: If you're using the [Google Maps Geocoding Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html), as @hamczu suggests, then you should be getting the results like this:

```
{
 ... snip ...
 geometry: {
   location: LatLng,
   ... snip ...
 }
}
```

It sounds like you're not using the API methods for the `LatLng` object, but are instead trying to use its undocumented properties. Your question demonstrates one of the best reasons why this is a Bad Idea - the Google code is compressed and obfuscated, using short, arbitrary variable and property names, and Google may recompress its code at any time, arbitrarily changing these names. What it *won't* change is the function and attribute names in the [published API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) - that's the whole point of having an API to begin with, and the reason why developers should code against the API, not the "undocumented features" of the currently available code.

So the best approach is to use the [documented methods](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng):

```
var lat = result.geometry.location.lat();
var lng = result.geometry.location.lng();
```

Otherwise, your code will likely break every time Google recompresses its code.

Comment: He is using [Google Maps JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.html) not the Web Services with JSON output.

Comment: Ah, I see. The point still holds, since he's introspecting the `LatLng` object rather than using its API methods. I'll update.

Comment: Maybe he passes this JSON-like object to some API with JSON. I have done something similar in one of my projects - I have received this object thru Google Maps JS API, then I pass this object to my server in the JSON format. There I manually get the lat and lng with this bizzare property names.

Comment: Possible - if so, he'd be better off making the object himself, using the API, before sending it to a server.